# Aggregation on mongoid has-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, aggregation-framework

I want to do aggregation where a model has has-many relationship with other model.

My document is `A` which has has-many relationship with `B`.

```
order_settlements =  A.collection.aggregate(
    {
      "$match" =>
      {
      }
    },
    "$group" => {
      '_id' => {
      },
      'B' => { "$first" => "$B"},
     }
  )
```

I am not able to get anything in `B`, it always returns empty `[]`.

I tried using eager loading -

```
order_settlements =  A.includes(:B).collection.aggregate(
    {
      "$match" =>
      {
      }
    },
    "$group" => {
      '_id' => {
      },
      'B' => { "$first" => "$B"},
     }
  )
```

This didn't work either. Is it possible to do aggregation with has-many relationship? Please let me know how I can do it.

Comment: You cannot reference objects from another collection with MongoDB "period". Only one collection is ever accessed "by design". The best you can do is query the "related data" (child)  for "parent" indicators first ( prodived your model accommodates this ) and then pass the matched indicators as an `$in` operation on the parent ( again provided your model stores the child `_id` values ) for those documents that matched the criteria of the child. But it is with whatever syntax or helpers, two different queries.

Comment: @NeilLunn : Is it possible using  'unwind' ?

Comment: Not unless the documents are "actually embedded", which is the actual point. No "joins" here.

Comment: @NeilLunn : What about using the 'includes' ; http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes

Comment: How many times to people need to repeat this? There are no "joins"! You cannot reference data in a query that does not exist within the collection being queried. Any "plugins" or other methods are just "emulation". MongoDB ( the ultimate storage engine being used here ) does not do this.